# Sharepoint how to add field to list where field with such name already exists?

Tags: content-type, column, spfield, field-definition

I have sharepoint list 'Events' with field **Location**.

I am trying to add from web existing field  with **same internal name** from other package.

```
    var fields = contentType.ParentWeb.Fields;

 SPField fieldToAdd = null;
                foreach (SPField field in fields)
                {
                    if (field.Id == fieldId)
                    {
                        fieldToAdd = field;
                        break;
                    }
                }

 contentType.FieldLinks.Add(new SPFieldLink(fieldToAdd));
```

And i got exception:

```
A duplicate field name "Location" was found.
```

When i am adding this fields in sharepoint UI it will be changed to **Location0** and will be successfully added!

How to do actually the same in code? I want to add them both and its acceptable to change one internal name to Location0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did not get your code clearly, what is fieldId and how are you getting this fieldId? my guess is location is already there in the content type you can not add the same field again, create a new field if you wish, in that case your code will be (after foreach) -

```
string fldName = fields.Add(fieldToAdd.Title, fieldToAdd.Type, fieldToAdd.Required);
SPField newField = fields.GetField(fldName);
contentType.FieldLinks.Add(new SPFieldLink(newField));
```

In this case a new field is created with same display name and same type as fieldToAdd, but with different internal name (you dont have to worry about what the internal name is, system will determine) and add that field to your content type

P.S. - you should consider using break; after fieldToAdd = field;

:)

Comment: This field is stored in web.Fields collection. And i think that i cannot use fields.Add() because field that already added to web.Fields has complex initialization.So it will be better to use exisiting one.

Comment: then in that case, i think the field is already added to your content type, that's why you can not add it in the content type again

Comment: No. I dont have this field. I have default field "Location" (Sharepoint events content type) and my field also has "Location" internal name. So the issue to change it somehow like sharepoint does this when you adding field from UI.

Comment: You can not change the internal name of a column, please find the msdn documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.internalname.aspx , see it's a get only property no setter is defined, you have to create a new column for your case